# How to approximate contour into four points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have binary masks obtained from segmentation model, and I want to get four corners only of its contour that include majority of the points with minimal area as you can see in this image:
[image]

The corners are not necessarily forming a rectangle, and the mask is noisy:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried contour detection, approximation, and `minAreaRect`, but the rectangle is in many cases wider than the shape, and not minimal to the limit I want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
from os import path as osp
import cv2
import numpy as np

path = "seg_masks"
im_list = os.listdir(path)

def lcc(binary_image:np.ndarray)->np.ndarray:
    # Find connected components
    print(binary_image.shape, binary_image.dtype)
    num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binary_image, connectivity=8)
    # Find the label (index) of the largest connected component
    largest_component_label = np.argmax(stats[1:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]) + 1  # Skip background label (0)
    largest_component_mask = (labels == largest_component_label).astype(np.uint8)
    largest_component_mask = largest_component_mask.astype(np.uint8)
    return largest_component_mask

for img_name in im_list:
    bgr_img_mask = cv2.imread(osp.join(path, img_name), 0)
    cv2.imwrite(osp.join(path, "white", img_name), bgr_img_mask)
    lcc_mask = lcc(bgr_img_mask)
    # Erosion to clean the mask contour a bit
    cl_ker = 5
    kernel = np.ones((cl_ker, cl_ker), np.uint8)
    erosion = cv2.erode(lcc_mask,kernel,iterations = 3)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
        lcc_mask, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, 
        method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE
    )
    if(len(contours)):
        max_cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        epsilon = 0.008 * cv2.arcLength(max_cnt, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(max_cnt, epsilon, True)
        approx = np.squeeze(np.array(approx, dtype=int), axis=1)

        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(approx) 
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect) 
        box = np.int0(box) 
        bgr_img_mask = cv2.drawContours(bgr_img_mask, [box], 0, 200, 2) 

        cv2.drawContours(bgr_img_mask, [approx], -1, 128, 2)
        bgr_img_mask = cv2.putText(bgr_img_mask, f"{round(epsilon,2)}", (50, 50) , 
                                   cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX , 1, 255, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    win_name = "img"
    cv2.namedWindow(win_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow(win_name, bgr_img_mask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

output:

[image]

Can you please guide me on how to do that? thanks.

Comment: have you tried using `cv2.open()`? This usually is very helpful when there are thin (relatively) protrusions

Comment: Also, what do you mean with the first image where the box is pink? Because this is not a rectangle, this is a trapezoid...

Comment: approxPolyDP is a really "simple" (dumb) algorithm. its advantage is that it is predictable. what you want is to find new corners that weren't there before. you don't actually want to find corners though. you want to find the straight lines that are in the data. NO DO NOT use Hough or Canny, if you thought of that just now. awful idea. forget those names right away.

Comment: as for solving your actual problem (https://xyproblem.info/), you should show us your source data. *unfiltered*.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz `approxPolyDP` indeed works well if the borders of the shape are clean, but I want to ensure that the output is only four points, this question is a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the provided masks are my staring point (X) as I have no control over the DL model.

Comment: You can make approxPolyDP output the correct number of points by looping through epsilon values until it returns 4 points. This is fairly reliable and not too slow.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is only "How to", without code. I hope this could be a bit help for you.)

I Started `minAreaRect` result for max area size contour, optimizing the 4-vertex position.

Objective function to minimize is defined as average distance from the contour edge along the square.
This can be calculated with OpenCV's `distanceTransform` and `LineIterator`.

Result for each 3 sample images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: minimzing `cv2.pointPolygonTest(contour, (int(vertex[0]), int(vertex[1])), True)` didn't work well also

Comment: `pointPolygonTest` seems for 1 point. I think, you should evaluate for all points on your square's edge lines. What I said in this post is such way.