# Detect and extract four points of quadrilaterals in an binary image using opencv / python / any AI/ML model

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I have binary segmented mask images like this
[image: input image]

I want to detect four co-ordinates of quadrilaterals from images like this
[image: output image]

```
output object = [ ( (x11,y11), (x12,y12), (x13,y13), (x14,y14) ) , # for first quadrilateral
                  ( (x21,y21), (x22,y22), (x23,y23), (x24,y24) ) ] # for second quadrilateral
```

I have tried Document scanning methods which using edge detection techniques but cant able to find four points of quadrilateral.

I can able to get the co-ordinates of the corner points by this code but don't able to create quadrilaterals from it.

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('../masks\cpu-b-model\segmentation4.png',0)

cnts = cv2.findContours(image.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
output = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(output, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
text = "original, num_pts={}".format(len(c))
# cv2.putText(output, text, (x, y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Original Contour", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(text)

for eps in np.linspace(0.05, 0.1, 10):
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, eps * peri, True)
    print(approx)
    output = image.copy()
    cv2.drawContours(output, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    text = "eps={:.4f}, num_pts={}".format(eps, len(approx))
    cv2.putText(output, text, (x, y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    print("[INFO] {}".format(text))
    cv2.imshow("Approximated Contour", output)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: it seems to be a topological problem, splitting a non-convex figure  into 2 convex ones and (I think!) one should study the neighbours of each corner. I tried to filter all possible quadrilaterals out of the `approxPolyDP` using `isContourConvex` and removing area duplicates but it wasn't enough

Comment: Find the collinear points along each edge and take the furtherest pair.

Comment: If i remember correctly, there was a question before with many answers addressing the same problem, can't seem to find it now...

Comment: Do you want to extract 4-points and then extract another 4-points?

Comment: Managed to find one of the posts that I had in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77787715/16815358 Sadly no implementation included

Comment: show us the unfiltered source image. we need to understand why that shape isn't just a quad, why there is that piece sticking to it.

Comment: I have a very unreliable solution based on filtering the distance transform, so far. Otherwise, since the contour is easy to separate by looking at the column-wise sum, this solution might be feasible in getting an ROI where the `findContours` function can be applied: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77884124/drawing-contours-on-captcha-image/77884823#77884823

Comment: @toyotaSupra No, all the quadrilateral co-ordinates at same time. Not one by one